# springboot not loading Jade pages from controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, pug, jade4j

I am a beginner in Spring. I am trying to build login page for an application. The problem is I am not able to load the login page from the controller. Below is the code for controller.

```
@RestController
public class RootViewController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {

    Map map = Collections.singletonMap("title", "Welcome! Login the website");
    return new ModelAndView("sites/test", map);
}
  }
```

The method returns status 404 error. The test page is in jade. The configuration file code is given below.

```
@Configuration
class JadeConfig {

@Bean
public SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader() {
    SpringTemplateLoader templateLoader = new SpringTemplateLoader();
    templateLoader.setBasePath("classpath:template/");
    templateLoader.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateLoader.setSuffix(".jade");
    return templateLoader;
}

@Bean
public JadeConfiguration jadeConfiguration() {
    JadeConfiguration configuration
            = new JadeConfiguration();
    configuration.setCaching(false);
    configuration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader());
    return configuration;
}
 }
```

The test file exists in resources/template/sites

[image: file location]

below is the gradle dependencies

```
    //Spring
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
compile group: 'de.neuland-bfi', name: 'spring-jade4j', version: '1.2.5'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

The client page test should run on port 8081 set through configuration file.

```
server:
port: 8081
```

Comment: Use `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`.

Comment: @M.Deinum this does not solve it.

Comment: It also doesn't look like you have a `ViewResolver` for jade configured, looks like that is missing.

Comment: @M.Deinum thankyou that solved the problem. If you want you can post it as an answer and I can acccept it.